# React Native - Flatlist - onEndReached not called and Infinite Scroll

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have some troubles implementing an Infinite Scroll on a Flatlist.

My flatlist has three columns, the "onEndReached" props is only called two times when the flatlist is loaded, but never again when I scroll to the end.
I notice that it works fine if I have only one column. 
Is there any bug or did I missed something ?

I read this video tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=99&v=rY0braBBlgw
The only difference is that I don't use fetch but axios, and I have 3 columns.

I also tried with a Scrollview over the Flatlist, and the `onScroll` and props, it works fine but the images in the flatlist are "flashing" when new items are added to the flatlist data.
Here is the sample code of what I'm doing :

```
this.props.myStore.getMyData().then((response) => { // getMyData is an axios request
    this.props.myStore.data = [...this.props.myStore.data.peek(), ...response.data];
    this.props.myStore.offset = this.props.myStore.data.length;
    this.setState({loading: false})
}).catch(() => {
    this.setState({loading: false})
    this.props.myStore.data = null;
});
```

And the Flatlist data is `this.props.myStore.data`

Thanks.

Comment: You should not update your props values inside your component. Its a bad practice. You should set them as state value and update your state with `setState`.

Comment: I found answer here , I initially tried all solutions given in github comments nothing worked, but finally check this answer which worked for me. Hope it will work for other too.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48740770/react-native-flatlist-pagination-not-working-onendreached-doesnt-fired/48747461#48747461