# React Native FlatList Pagination not working - onEndReached doesn't fired

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using react-native FlatList component to list of items
Pagination is not happening as expected , as per documentation onEndReached has to get fired when end of page is reached, currently I tried changing the values for onEndReachedThreshold ( tried 0.1, 1.0, 0.5, 0.01 ), am setting refreshing flag as well. 
Note: I am using ReactNative 0.48.4
So here my code

```
<Container style={{ marginTop: 22 }}>
      <Content
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
      >
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <FlatList
            initialNumToRender={10}
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
            onEndReached={({ distanceFromEnd }) => {
              console.log('on end reached ', distanceFromEnd);
            }}
            data={this.props.messages}
            renderItem={this.notificationContent.bind(this)}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
          />
        </View>
      </Content>
    </Container>
```

I have already tried all possible solutions as give in responses for [github issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351592/reactnative-flatlist-onendreached-not-working)

Any Help here ?

Comment: Your `Content` component style "flexGrow" may do some weird things with the flatlist.

Comment: onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}    remove this line and check, it will work for sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use NativeBase in your project and the Flatlist is on Content they are conflict. To solve this problem you need to remove Content

Comment: In general, having `FlatList` inside any `ScrollView` can cause problems

Comment: having the `FlatList` inside the [`SafeArea`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview.html) view caused the problem on android

Answer (score 5):

Same thing happens with me you need to add contentContainerStyle={flex:1}

```
<Content contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass extraData prop to FlatList as `extraData = {this.state}` check the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) for more  info.

Comment: I need to fetch extra data when user scrolls to end ( fetching next page), this answer is for some other purpose .

Comment: I understood your query, I use FlatList in one of my apps, for you to re-render FlatList, you need to pass `this.state` to `extraData`, and then pass the new data set to `data`, that it will work. Otherwise if you keep passing new data sets alone, you will see nothing changing as you have been seeing. Please refer to the docs.

Comment: Where is new data ? when to get new data ? I have to call API to get new data, when to call API ? when user scrolls to the end of the current list then I have to make a call. the whole requirement itself is to get new data. so probably your case is different

Comment: This is my assumption or rather what I would expect, when `onEndReached` is triggered, you call `this.props.messages`, which I assume to be a `state` array object of parent class and there you push more messages to the object. But FlastList extends PureComponent and won't simply re-render on state change, so you pass `this.state` of parent Component to `extraData` as `this.props.someVariableHolding"this.State"` this will cause the FlatList to reload and re-render

Comment: you are not getting my question, my problem is onEndReached itself is not triggered if that is triggered my problem is solved. Kindly go through my problem statement again, also my question title clearly says onEndReached doesn't fired

Comment: onEndReached  didn't triggered in my case as well. But setting extraData={this.state} worked and onEndReached starts to trigger as well.

Comment: Setting `extraData={this.state}` didn't fix anything for me.

Answer (score -7):

```
onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}     remove this line
```

Comment: And how do you expect to call onEndReached? Also a default is set for onEndReachedThreshold.